# Clutch fails to fully disengage, order of diagnosis

Tags: clutch, skoda, clutch-hydraulics, fabia

I'm about to get my hands on a 2001 Skoda Fabia 1.4 MPI (6Y) Manual which has a clutch fault.  The clutch does not slip and once the car is moving, it's possible to drive it relatively normally.  However, from stationary, it's impossible to go from neutral to first gear because the clutch doesn't fully disengage when the pedal is pressed.

I have no idea what the cause is as I've not had any time with the car other than a cursory glance under the bonnet to see that it's a hydraulic clutch and the master cylinder is shared with the brakes.  I was going to start by bleeding the system and also seeing if there is any adjustment possible on the slave cylinder or release arm.  The objective being to try as many things as possible before having to 1. spend any money or 2. removing the bell housing.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what else to check or know anything relevant specific to this model?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really mean that the reservoir is shared with the brakes, not the master cylinder?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I mean.  The clutch uses the same reservoir as the brakes and that has plenty of relatively clean looking fluid in it.

Comment: What was the final diagnosis on this?

Comment: @HandyHowie failed clutch, one of the fingers on the splines was damaged.  Replacement clutch resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the only thing I think of (and had it before - different car though) is that the clutch center plate is sticking on the input shaft splines and thus being held against either one of the friction faces...

Or the center plate is stuck to the flywheel face... but that can be freed...

One other thing to check is that the slave cylinder is giving the linear movement it should and that the arm is then moving correctly - some had plastic pivot bushes thst would collapse causing the pressure plate not to move sufficiently...